# Dockerfile vs Docker Compose (Java)

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I had the dockerfile and it worked well but I wanted to try with compose.
My issue is that the jar is never found. How can I say to the compose that it must build the jar using `mvn clean package` and pick the jar from `../api/target` ??

> global-hall-of-fame-api    | Error: Unable to access jarfile global-hall-of-fame.jar

**Dockerfile (works)**

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/global-hall-of-fame.jar global-hall-of-fame.jar
EXPOSE 8083
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "global-hall-of-fame.jar"]
```

And then...

```
docker run --name global-hall-of-fame-api -d --link global-hall-of-fame-db:global-hall-of-fame-db -p 8083:8083 global-hall-of-fame-api
```

**Docker Compose (doesn't work)**

```
version: '3'
services:
  global-hall-of-fame-db:
    container_name: global-hall-of-fame-db
    image: mysql:8.0.18
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: global-hall-of-fame-db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
  global-hall-of-fame-api:
    container_name: global-hall-of-fame-api
    depends_on: 
      - global-hall-of-fame-db
    restart: always
    build: ../api
    working_dir: /global-hall-of-fame-api
    volumes:
      - ./:/global-hall-of-fame-api
      - ~/.m2:/root/.m2
    expose:
      - "8083"
    command: "mvn clean spring-boot:run"
```

Comment: try removing this line:     working_dir: /global-hall-of-fame-api and command: "mvn clean spring-boot:run"

Comment: Also please provide the error too